# Remove delay from php's error_log file

Tags: php, debugging, error-logging, error-log

I can't find an answer to this anywhere, so I'm asking here.

I'm just wondering if there's a way where I can see an error instantly printed into the php's error_log file when the error happens. Right now, my server is a standard setup running with cpanel/whm and the CPU usage and memory usage are always at normal levels.

The crazy thing is when errors happen, it seems I have to wait five minutes or more to see the entry in the php error_log file. If I check the log file right after I generate the error, then it doesn't get printed.

What can I do to minimize the waiting time for new errors to appear in the php's error_log file from the time the errors happen?

Comment: This is nothing you can "fix", since it is not caused by any issue. Actually the entries into the error log file (or any other log file apache writes) _are_ written instantly. The issue you face is that your service provider does not allow access to that log file. Instead you are provided a projection of the original file with entries only added in a delayed fashion. That means this is out of your control. If at all you would have to address your hosting provider _why_ they offer such bad performance in that details.

Comment: However another thing to mention is that _usually_ one is not interested in live error messages _on a production site_. Development is another thing, but that certainly should not be done on a hosted service, but locally where you have full control yourself. Only tested and released versions should be transferred to the hosting provider.

Comment: I'm in charge of the dedicated server in which the website runs from. I have ssh access. I want to collect error details to help me improve website performance.

Comment: That sounds very different from what I understood from your question. Never saw anyone using `cPanel` in an own system... In that case it would indeed be interesting what actually causes that delay you describe. If you _really_ look at the right logfile, then entries should appear immediately. There is nothing that might cause a delay there. How to you monitor that file?

Comment: I do a manual check-up of the file when I suspect something is wrong with the performance or appearance of a webpage.

Comment: Sure, but what I was referring to was which utility you use for that manual peek. Just to eliminate that there is an issue with changes in the file getting picked up by your monitoring only delayed.

Comment: at the time, nothing

Comment: @Mike did you ever solve this, I too have this curious anomaly and it's driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

It is a workaround not solution for the delay isssue. You can add this line at the end  of your function

```
error_log(PHP_EOL, 3, $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

For php-fpm, I found this option at https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php - set it to no:

```
log_buffering bool
Experimental logging without extra buffering. Default value: yes. Available as of PHP 7.3.0.
```